# The efficiency of two merged heat engines

Tags: thermodynamics

What is the efficiency of a heat engine that gets $Q_1$ and gives $W_1$ and $Q_c$ and another heat engine that gets $Q_c$ and gives $W_2$ and $Q_{c2}$.
The efficiency of the first engine is $\eta_1$ and efficiency of the second machine is $\eta_2$.

Answer (score 0):

What's the definition of efficiency? The total amount of work extracted divided by the energy taken in from the hot source: $$\eta = \frac{W}{Q_{\mathrm{hot}}}. $$ This works regardless of the form the engine takes, how many sub-engines it has, etc. The first law of thermodynamics allows for the relationship to be transformed to: $$\eta = 1 - \frac{Q_{\mathrm{cold}}}{Q_{\mathrm{hot}}}.$$ Again, $Q_{\mathrm{hot}}$ is the heat exchanged with the hot reservoir, and $Q_{\mathrm{cold}}$ is the heat exchanged with the cold reservoir, no matter how many intermediate steps are taken.

Comment: You that the total efficiency is n1+n2? Iknow that the total efficiency is (W1+W2)/Qhot but i just want to have n1 and n2 in thw awnser.

Comment: $$\begin{align}\eta_1 &= 1 - \frac{Q_1}{Q_c} \\
\eta_2 &= 1 - \frac{Q_{c}}{Q_{c2}} \\
\eta_{tot} & = 1 - \frac{Q_1}{Q_{c2}}.\end{align}$$ The rest is algebraic manipulations to find the answer in the terms you want. One path: solve the first two equations for $Q_1$ and $Q_{c2}$, respectively, and substitute the results into the third equation.

Comment: Sorry but the problem is the algebraic manipulation

Comment: Here I only have the ability to give you an answer, which would be to your overall detriment when you are expected to do a similar task on a test. I would suggest you turn to resources about solving systems of equations. For example the [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra-basics/alg-basics-systems-of-equations) has material and exercises to help you master the topic.